# Inline boxplots using sparkline

Tags: javascript, r, datatable, sparklines

I have a dataset as shown below

```
 ID       MinTemp     MaxTemp     Quartile1     Quartile2     Quartile3
 28       19          88          23            63            80
 43       18          78          25            57            77
 11       34          118         52            81            101
```

I am interested in learning how to create an `inline boxplot` for each row based on their corresponding, `Min`, `Max`, `Quartile1`, `Quartile2`, `Quartile3` values using the sparkline package.

The final output should look like this below

[image]

Any help on accomplishing this is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a method @missy morrow?

Comment: I just posted the following similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72100688/r-shiny-table-with-sparkline-boxplot but no luck so far

Answer (score 1):

One of the options is to use `sparkline::spk_chr` which is a wrapper for a `jquery.sparkline` solution. The raw = TRUE has to be set so you will be expected to provide the low_outlier, low_whisker, q1, median, q3, high_whisker, high_outlier not the raw data points. When the `showOutliers = FALSE` is set then the outliers stats should not be provided.

Updated part of ?sparkline::spk_chr help page:

```r
library(sparkline)
library(formattable)
set.seed(1234)
fw <- as.htmlwidget(
    formattable(
        data.frame(
            id = c("a", "b", "c"),
            sparkline = c(
                # low_outlier, low_whisker, q1, median, q3, high_whisker, high_outlier
                spk_chr(c(-3, -3, 1, 2, 3, 6, 6), type="box", raw = TRUE, width = 200),
                # low_whisker, q1, median, q3, high_whisker
                spk_chr(c(-3, 1, 2, 3, 6), type="box", raw = TRUE, width = 200, showOutliers = FALSE),
                # raw data
                spk_chr(rnorm(10), type="box", width = 200)
            ),
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE
        )
    )
)
spk_add_deps(fw)
```

Comment: This is great.  Is there a way to specify multiple outliers with `raw = TRUE`?  Will sparkline accept a list where the outlier elements are vectors?